# How to use Python to get local admins from a computer on the network?

Tags: python, active-directory, winreg

I need to get a list of all people in the company who have local admin rights on their computers. We have a group on each machine called "Administrators." I can get a list of all computers from Active Directory with:

```
import active_directory

for computer in active_directory.search ("objectCategory='Computer'"):
  print computer.displayName
```

I think I need to take each computer name and feed it back in. I was thinking maybe reading the remote registry on each computer and looking for the SID -- supposedly the SID 'S-1-5-domain-500' will give me a list of people on the computer that are local admins. I did:

```
import _winreg
COMPUTER_NAME = "FakeComputerName"
KEY_PATH = r"System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName"
HKLM_remote = _winreg.ConnectRegistry (r"\\%s" % COMPUTER_NAME, _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
hKeyRemote = _winreg.OpenKey (HKLM_remote, KEY_PATH, 0, _winreg.KEY_READ)
value, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx (hKeyRemote, "ComputerName")
print "Remote computer name is", value
Remote computer name is FakeComputerName
```

How do I combine these to get what I need? Will these work together? Is this the best way to go about this? Once I get this to work I can figure out writing it to a file and adding exceptions like if the computer isn't on the network it writes that and then moves onto the next PC. Perhaps use win32security?

I don't know what registry key to use or even if it will work. I've spent about 5 hours on this today and I am still learning Python. I don't know VB and that is the majority of code I see on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the data from this operation going to be manipulated afterwards? If this is a manual scan that is going to be looked at by a human, then you're way overthinking it.

Just use a network scanner to handle it for you, such as [this one](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the details but it sounds like you may want to take a look at the [WMI](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) package.

Back when I was playing with COM and the windows registry and ran across it.  It looks like it's been improved a bit since when I looked at it.

Here's windows reference documentation. [WMI Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572(VS.85).aspx)